# Gatsby - how to use third party dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, gatsby

I've to use `bootstrap-select`, `bootstrap`, `jquery`, `popper`, `isotope`, `wow` and a script file that uses all these libs with Gatsby.  I did like this in `layout.js`:

```
import React from "react"
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
import "./vendors/themify-icon/themify-icons.css"
import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
import "./vendors/flaticon/flaticon.css"
import "animate.css/animate.min.css"
import "./vendors/magnify-pop/magnific-popup.css"
import "./layout.css"
import "./responsive.css"
import "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
import "popper.js/dist/popper"
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
import "bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"
import "wowjs/dist/wow.min.js"
import "jquery.scroll-parallax/dist/js/jquery.scrollParallax.js"
import "./vendors/isotope/isotope-min.js"
import "./vendors/magnify-pop/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"
import Loader from "./loader"
import Header from "./header"
import Breadcrumb from "./breadcrumb"
```

**Is this a correct way to import all these dependencies ?**
During gatsby develop I am not sure it works or not but I am not getting any errors. During gatsby build it failed. So, I copied all these files to static and build passed.

Then I checked for all these files in common.js but not a single file code is there. **How do I use all these dependencies with Gatsby ?**

Comment: Why don't you use the npm packages instead? Like react-popper and reactstrap?

Comment: @Aldo I am trying to use Saasland template which had all these dependencies. Not sure which dependency supports react and works with gatsby.